# И еще о пунктуации

Tags: орфография, пунктуация

Оттуда же. Собственно, читаю на одном из сообществ выдержки из учительских записей в школьных дневниках и комментирую. Цитирую запись и комментарий:
"Объясните своему сыну, что есть тетради необязательно, если у него нет домашнего задания!"
Комментарий: "А если есть (—) то обязательно".
Так вот, нужно ли тут тире? И правильно ли написано слово "необязательно"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Совсем непонятен смысл высказывания! Формально - в предложении есть составной союз если..то, перед второй частью союза ставится запятая. Тире возможно как интонационное, как авторский знак.

Слово необязательно написано правильно. Впрочем, если бы было написано раздельно, то тоже верно. Все зависит от смысла, который вкладывает автор: утверждает необязательность- слитно, отрицает обязательность - раздельно.

Answer (score 0):

А я думаю, что здесь как раз уместно тире: предложение неполное. Смысл комментария: *А если есть домашнее задание, то тетради есть обязательно*.

Answer (score 0):

> > > Объясните своему сыну, что есть тетради необязательно, если у него нет домашнего задания

:lol:, :смайлик-ФейсомОбТэйбл:, :смайлик-АффтфырПешыЫсдчо: 
Тире нужно, комментарий не обязателен. Этот перл самодостаточен. Краду в коллекцию.